# jQuery cycle: more scrollHorz effects inside each slide

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-cycle, jquery-effects

I create [scrollHorz slideshow](http://jsfiddle.net/kubedan/pHUXB/) where i want animate divs inside slide.

I want like this jquery pseudocode
`$(".item .top").startSlideHorz();`
`$(".item .middle .left").delay(100).startSlideHorz();`
`$(".item .middle .right").delay(200).startSlideHorz();`
`$(".item .bottom").delay(300).startSlideHorz();`

I inspirated on http://www.goldmansachs.com

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemInner">
        <div class="top">First top</div>
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="left">First left</div> 
          <div class="right">First right</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">First bottom</div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemInner">
        <div class="top">Second top</div>
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="left">Second left</div> 
          <div class="right">Second right</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">Second bottom</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> 
      <div class="itemInner">
        <div class="top">Third top</div>
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="left">Third left</div> 
          <div class="right">Third right</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">Third bottom</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate any idea
Thanks.

Comment: I found inspiration on http://stackoverflow.com/a/5108258/1102223 and I continue in [work](http://jsfiddle.net/kubedan/pHUXB/4/).

Comment: What's the question? I am a little confused

Comment: I try create something like http://www.goldmansachs.com by jquery cycle

Comment: Wow that's.....quite a question to ask, I see why no one has answered. Really people tend to answer for localised questions since this question would require a huge amount of time and effort that normally they get paid for...hmm I might take a look at it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=) ... http://jsfiddle.net/4B49x/1